# The Apple phone is connected to the computer, and the computer can't recognize the device

Tags: iphone, windows-10, itunes

I tried to connect my iPhone with windows 10. The phone can be charged, but the computer doesn't recognize the mobile device.

Then I also tried to add a driver, but I didn't find the `Drivers` folder under `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Apple\Mobile Device Support\`

Please help me ,it already took me a long time.

---

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check few things in order to make this work...-
**I would say restart your phone once before you proceed further.**

1. Check window update of iTunes and update it.
2. Goto control panel-->device manager-->universal serial bus--> then apple mobile device-->Clicked on driver-->then on update driver-->FIXED it. laptop now sees my ipone when plugged in. EASY! Way less trouble than other posts here! Mine was not working since the 13.1.1 IOS update.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have tried to restart my mobile phone and computer. I have uninstalled and reinstalled iTunes many times, and it is the latest version,but it didn't work.
The problem with the second method is that I can't find an apple mobile device under my universal serial bus.

Comment: @LouraQ Follow these to find universal serial bus..
First, make sure you have iTunes and Apple Mobile Device Support Installed.
1. Go to Device Manager
2. Locate your Apple device (mine was under Portable Devices. It's very possible it's somewhere else for you.)
3. Right click it and select "Update Device Driver."
4. Navigate to C:\Program Files\Common Files\Apple\Mobile Devices\Support\Drivers and select that folder
5. Hit next. The driver should install and you'll see "Apple Mobile Device USB Driver" under the "Universal Serial Device USB Driver" section in Device Manager.

Comment: The problem is that I cannot find the "Driver" folder. But I have successfully connected to the iphone because I replaced the original data cable to connect. The reason for this low-level error is because I successfully connected with that data cable a few days ago, so I excluded the data cable from the beginning. It's stupid.
I compared the folder changes before and after the connection was successful, and it seemed to have nothing to do with these.
But thank you very much for your serious answer.